# Trying to display stick or featured post on homepage

Tags: posts, homepage

Im trying to add the last sticky post to a section on my homepage as a Featured article. I have created this so far and it displays posts but not the sticky ones:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts'),'showposts' => 1 )); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(''); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I have tried to change the query_posts to  get_post. The problem then is that it displays the other 3 'latest news' posts from the other loop at the top of the page.

Any help would be really really appreciated

Comment: The normal loop for getting posts should automatically put sticky posts at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'showposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => date, 
    'order' => 'desc'
);

$sticky = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $sticky->have_posts() ):
    while ( $sticky->have_posts() ): $sticky->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: @ste, nice to hear it. You can accept the answer so the question will be marked as anwered.